# VBA Delete Range Content Error

Tags: vba

I want to clear the contents of column B from line 2 to the last filled cell. As I am working with several open workbooks at the same time I need to make sure the correct Range gets deleted.
When I use this code I'm getting the error `1004 - run time error`:

```
Workbooks("BO_Settings.xlsm").Activate
intLastRow = _
    Workbooks("BO_Settings.xlsm") _
        .Worksheets(strCurrentSheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count

Workbooks("BO_Settings.xlsm") _
    .Worksheets(strCurrentSheet).Range( _
          Cells(2, 2) _
        , Cells(intLastRow, 2) _
    ).ClearContents
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which cell you are using inside the range.

```
Dim wS as worksheet
Set wS = Workbooks("BO_Settings.xlsm").Worksheets(strCurrentSheet)

Range(wS.Cells(2,2), wS.Cells(intLastRow,2)).ClearContents
```

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for your help sir! Runs great now. :-)